# SignalR WebAPI - Push message not received

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr

My angularclient is able to invoke the serverhub. But never receive push messages from the server, send with this line:
`hub.Clients.All.serverTime(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());`

For debug purposes I've added `console.log(...)` in the subscription (signalrhubproxy.js):

```
proxy.on(eventName, function (result) {
      console.log('event:' + eventName + ' received.' ); <--- never fired
      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          if (callback) {
              callback(result);
          }
      });
});
```

I've followed this tutorial [Pushing Data: Integrating with ASP.NET SignalR Hubs](http://henriquat.re/server-integration/signalr/integrateWithSignalRHubs.html) wih a few 
modifications in my app:

- it has a WebAPI structure with a startup.cs, with this SignalR configuration:

  ```
      app.Map("/signalr", map =>
      {
          map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
          var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
          {
              EnableDetailedErrors = true,
              EnableJSONP = true
          };
          map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
      });
  ```

  instead of this in the global.asax:

  RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration 
              { EnableCrossDomain = true });

  ```
      AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
  ```
- The WebAPI runs on localhost:2034 (VS)
- The Client runs on localhost:9000 (grunt)

I'm able to:
- invoke the servermethod `getServerTime` from the client.
- run the `BackgroundServerTimeTimer`
- get the `hub` in the `BackgroundServerTimeTimer` with:

`hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ClientPushHub>();`

and notifies the clients with:

`hub.Clients.All.serverTime(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()); <--- no error serverside, no glory clientside`

Is it my box?
- My box runs on Windows 7 and has VS 2013

**UPDATE**
I've implemented the simple ['Getting started chatsample'](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) without changes in the server config. And that's working. So, it's clear that it's a clientside problem in my angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

`app.js` has a value: `.value('signalRServer', 'http://localhost:2032/')`

The example from the website creates hubproxies like this, without usage of the .value:

```
function ServerTimeController($scope, signalRHubProxy) {
    var clientPushHubProxy = signalRHubProxy(
        signalRHubProxy.defaultServer, 'clientPushHub', <--- signalRHubProxy.defaultServer should be: signalRServer
            { logging: true });
    var serverTimeHubProxy = signalRHubProxy(
        signalRHubProxy.defaultServer, 'serverTimeHub'); <--- signalRHubProxy.defaultServer should be: signalRServer

    clientPushHubProxy.on('serverTime', function (data) {
        $scope.currentServerTime = data;
        var x = clientPushHubProxy.connection.id;
    });

    $scope.getServerTime = function () {
        serverTimeHubProxy.invoke('getServerTime', function (data) {
            $scope.currentServerTimeManually = data;
        });
    };
};
```

For completeness, the right way:

```
angular.module('yourApp').controller('yourCtrl', function ($scope, signalRHubProxy, signalRServer ) {

            var clientPushHubProxy = signalRHubProxy(
                signalRServer, 'clientPushHub',
                { logging: true });
            var serverTimeHubProxy = signalRHubProxy(
                signalRServer, 'serverTimeHub',
                { logging: true });

            clientPushHubProxy.on('serverTime', function (data) {

                $scope.currentServerTime = data;
                //jshint unused:false
                var x = clientPushHubProxy.connection.id;

                console.log('Client pushhubproxy id: ' + x );

            });
 .....
```

Comment: Strange issue left. I've merged the project with the simple chat sample. When I remove the alert from the page, the push is not received. I think, the connection needs some time. But a blocking call with an alert box is ugly...

Answer (score 0):

The real problem: I was digging around with different signalR versions and a old version of the example.

Here is the version for SignalR 2 located: [signalr angular example](https://github.com/ChristianWeyer/ngSignalR/blob/V2/ngSignalR/app/js/services.js)